# How log broadcast in logcat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, logcat

I am trying to find which broadcast is being sent on language change when user changes language in the settings.

How do I log this in my console. I have a lot of logs popping up and can't seem to get it. Is there a way to log that?

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to find which broadcast is being sent on language change when user changes language in the settings.

You are probably looking for [`ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED).

> How do I log this in my console

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for this broadcast, and have it log a message to LogCat, using the `Log` class, from its `onReceive()` method.

Comment: Do I need any permission for this?

Comment: @user3547028: Not that I am aware of.